# How to append new properties to the form data object from reactive from?

Tags: angular

As you can see currently i send the form data as `this.loginForm.value` now the thing is that I have too more properties `planId` and `service` that I want to send along with the data.
One way is that i recreate the object as below and send it but it is not convenient.

```
const userDetails = {
    email: this.loginForm.controls.email.value,
    password: this.loginForm.controls.password.value,
    planId: this.planId,
    service: this.service
    }
```

...

```
export class LoginComponent
          planId = "2";
          service = "seo";
          ngOnInit() {
            this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
              email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
              password: ['', Validators.required]
            })

            onSubmit() {

            this.auth.loginUser(this.loginForm.value).subsribe((res)=>{
             ........
            })
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help

```
const objData = Object.assign({'planId' : this.planId, 'service': this.service},this.loginForm.value);

this.auth.loginUser(objData ).subsribe((res)=>{
    ........
})
```

Comment: it will create object

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try like this...

```
let data = this.loginForm.value;
data['planId'] = this.planId;
data['service'] = this.service;
this.auth.loginUser(data).subsribe((res)=>{
    ........
})
```